# To add offset with the UTC date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Dates in database(SQL) are in UTC. I want to get the dates based on the Timezone.
Say for example if it's IST (UTC+05:30) then I want to get the IST date and time in database. If anyone knows, please guide me to do operation in database (I have date and offset of the particular timezone).

Comment: Can you show us a scenario and the output you desire? Also your attempt on this problem.

Comment: If you're asking about how to do this within SQL, it's not clear to me why you've labelled this as a C# question. If you're happy to do it within your C# code, it's reasonably straightforward. If you really want to do it in your database, it's considerably trickier in general, although https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport probably does what you want.

Comment: i want to add/subtract the offset with the date in sql

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The answer will vary depending on the DBMS you're using.

Comment: you can use case statement to change your dates based on other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged as SQL Server 2008 so you will be able to use [DATETIMEOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb630289.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No easy & generic method exists if you want to be able to display dates from the past or future. The problem is that you have to take DST at the date into account.

The easiest way is to add a .Net assembly to your database to manage this.